# Отсутсвует класс Hashtable

Tags: c#

Создаю библиотеку с такими целевыми платформами:
[image: 1]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Вроде есть, но вот класс Hashtable почему-то отсутствует, хотя тот же list есть.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А чем `Dictionary` не устраивает?

Comment: А в чем отличие от hashtable?

Comment: Основное - это обобщенный тип, поэтому при работе с value type не будет боксинга. Плюс, если я не ошибаюсь, Hashtable был потокобезопасен. Если нужна потокобезопасность, используйте ConcurrentDictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashtable в WinRT отсутствует. Вместо него действительно советуют использовать

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
```